# Can I ask, how to detect Palmaris longus muscle?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, specific-question

I have written a comment

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dE5KNQHVlak&lc=UgxsXp-ac89rMIdraeV4AaABAg

> "Palmaris longus muscle" article in wikipedia shows it other way.
> there 1 muscle stands out in middle, and in your hand 2 muscles stand
> out in left and right side.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmaris_longus_muscle .

so, question appears, which of these correct? probably wikipedia is correct. but is this question on topic here?

Comment: It's not off topic but all I see is a bit of anatomical variation. I don't think the video or wikipedia is wrong.

Comment: maybe somebody here can give better, more full answer, showing several variants how it look when it present, and several variants when it is not present.

Comment: Then what would your question be if both sources are correct? Asking for a list of examples would be off topic.

Comment: I think that this is a valid question for this site! Do go ahead and ask it, that should be answerable. I do not think that a list of examples would be necessary!

Comment: i searched in google for "how to detect Palmaris longus muscle?" and first result is an article in "men's health", it contains a video by Institute of Human Anatomy. see from 6:22: https://youtu.be/yc1VgVw7F9w?t=6m22s . i think the man from the first video has shown flexor carpi radialis, which is more close to thumb.

Comment: i changed my mind. i checked some videos more and now i think, most important is how sharply does it stand out. seems he has that muscle.